# How to set up "DEGREES" "MINUTES" "SECONDS" in a table of a database?

Tags: degrees, libreoffice-base

I am going crazy to set up DEGREES MINUTES and SECONDS in a table of LibreOffice Base for Longitude and Latitude.
When I set TIME [HH].MM.SS in a column of cells of LibreOffice Calc and then I compile starting from value 180.00.00 and incrementing -000.00.01, then I see 180.00.00 and 179.59.59 and so continuing.
If I set TIME [HH].MM.SS in a field of LibreOffice Base and then I insert manually 180.00.00 then show me 12.00.00.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: degrees sounds as if you are trying to store coordinates (latitude/longitude) - `time` is definitely the wrong choice for that (how would "This afternoon at half past three" identify a location?) You probably should simply store those three values in three `double` columns

Comment: "THREE DOUBLE COLUMNS"?

Comment: Yes! I am working on a database of geographic coordinates of longitude and latitude with system sexagesimal.

With your answer, did you mean to create something like this?

TABLE LAT_DEGREES
ID_DEGREE
DEGREE

TABLE LAT_DEGREES_MINUTES
ID_DEGREES
ID_MINUTES

TABLE LAT_MINUTES
ID_MINUTE
MINUTE

TABEL LAT_MINUTES_SECONDS
ID_MINUTES
ID_SECONDS

TABLE LAT_SECONDS
ID_SECOND
SECOND

Then relation between the tables?

Did I understand correct or no?

Sorry, but I am not expert and I don't know what does mean "THREE DOUBLE COLUMNS".